# OnSuccessListener Not Firing getLastLocation()

Tags: java, android, listener

Working Example of grabbing location object

```
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    processActivityData();
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        // Logic to handle location object
                        locationList.add(location);
                    }
                }
            });
```

But i need to call getLastLocation() more than once so i want to implement it at class level but the event isnt firing. Something like this

```
public class StopWatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnSuccessListener {

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
}
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object o) {
        int test=0;
        test +=1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. I forgot to set listener when calling getLastLocation()

```
public class StopWatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnSuccessListener<Location>
...
fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this);
...
@Override
public void onSuccess(Location location) {
```